# Mean, Median, Variance calculator

Tags: java, methods, mean, median

I have created a program that calculates the mean, median, and variance. the program accepts up to 500 inputs. All of my methods work perfectly when there are 500 inputs (max size of my array). When there are less inputs, only the 'mean' calculator works. Here's the entire program:

```
    public class StatsPackage{

    static int i = 0, arrayLength;
    static double sum = 0, mean, median, sumOfSquares, variance, stdDev;

    static double calcMean (int inputs[], int count) throws IOException{
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            sum += inputs[i];
        }   
        mean = (sum/count);
        return mean;            
    }

    static double calcMedian (int inputs[], int count){
        Arrays.sort(inputs);
        if (count % 2 == 0){
            median = ((inputs[(count/2)] + inputs[(count/2)- 1])/2) ;
        }
        if (count % 2 != 0){
            median = inputs[(count-1)/2];           
        }
        return median;
    }

    static double calcVariance (int inputs[], int count){

        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            sumOfSquares += (inputs[i]*inputs[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            sum = sum + inputs[i];
        }
        variance = ((sumOfSquares/count) - (sum * sum)/(count * count));
        return variance;
    }

    static double calcStdDev (double varianceInput){
        stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance);
        return stdDev;
    }







  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String str = "test";
        int inputs[] = new int [500];
        int counter = 0;
        int i = 0;



        while ((str = stdin.readLine()) != null && i < 500) {
            inputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            i++;
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("Mean: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcMean(inputs, counter)));
        System.out.println("Median: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcMedian(inputs, counter)));
        System.out.println("Variance: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcVariance(inputs, counter)));
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcStdDev(variance)));
        }
    }
```

Here is an example output when 10 random numbers are entered:

Mean: 47.90
Median: 0.00
Variance: 0.00
Standard Deviation: 0.00

Here is the same code when 500 numbers are entered (the max size of my array):

Mean: 47.27
Median: 47.00
Variance: 856.71
Standard Deviation: 29.27

These outputs are consistent. I input 10 numbers, and I only get the mean method to work. I input 500 numbers and I get all of them working. I'm running this program against another tester program, not by inputting the numbers myself in eclipse. The tester program is my instructor's and I trust his program is working correctly.

Can anyone please help? I'm about to tear my hair out.

Comment: You're not initializing many of your variables.  Give me an example input and expected output.

Comment: input: 

49
66
73
56
3
39
33
77
54
29



output is supposed to be: 

Mean: 47.90
Median: 51.50
Variance: 458.29
Standard Deviation: 21.41

Comment: That is not the definition of variance. Variance is `sum((input[i]-mean)^2)/count`, not `sum(input[i]^2)/count-mean^2`...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are initializing an array of size 500, but then not using all 500 indices. That means you have an array like:

```
[2,5,3,7,8,2,......,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

So your code is going to calculate the median and std devation with all those `0`s. What you should be using is an `ArrayList`. An `ArrayList` will expand in size as you add elements, whereas a regular list cannot change size.

*If you cannot use an `ArrayList`, then you have to do a bit more work.*

```
while ((str = stdin.readLine()) != null && i < 500) {
            inputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            i++;
            counter++;
        }
```

Your `counter` variable already has the information you need. Now, before passing this array to your mean/median/stddev methods, you need to reduce the size of the array. The easiest way to do this is to use an existing method provided to all arrays, called `CopyOf()` : [CopyOf() method for Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)%22CopyOf()%20method%20for%20Arrays%22)

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, counter);
```

Now replace your old `input` array with your new `newArray` in your method calls:

```
System.out.println("Mean: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcMean(newArray, counter)));
        System.out.println("Median: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcMedian(newArray, counter)));
        System.out.println("Variance: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcVariance(newArray, counter)));
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation: " + nf.format(StatsPackage.calcStdDev(variance)));
```

Comment: I know I should use an array list, but the problem is our instructor does not allow us to use what "he hasnt taught us"

Comment: I dont know how he expects us to get this done by using a regular array

Comment: You could track the number of inputs and then slice the array after you're done collecting.

Comment: How exactly would I slice the array? resize it using some kind of if statement? and would that fix my problem of the non working methods for an array that isnt filled? thanks

Comment: @LandonWiggs ok, well then what you need to do is recreate a new array. Like @jgitter mentioned, you'll have to `splice` up the array. Create a new array, based on the number of entries inserted into your `[500]` array. This is a pretty bad way to do it though. Another way is to prompt the user asking, "How many numbers are in your data set?", and then use that number to create the array. But then you have to make sure the user puts in that many numbers.

Comment: @LandonWiggs I've updated my answer for you with a solution that does not use `ArrayList`, it's not so bad to accomplish.

Comment: Thats fantastic thanks so much I will use this. Thanks again this really helps!!!

Comment: The documentation on Java Arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

I assume you tested it with random *positive* integers, as it seems to be the case for these results.

When you input `n` (where `n` is small in comparison to 500) positive integers, your array is mostly full of 0's.
As `Array.sort` sorts the array in-place, `calcMedian` modifies the actual array passed, placing all these 0's to the front, and the median is, naturally, 0, as all `n` of them are in the back.
Then `calcVariance` calculates the variance of the first `n` 0's, as the array was sorted previously.
Finally, `calcStdDev` refers to the result of `calcVariance`.

To fix this, you should consider:

- Sorting the array with [this method taking a starting and ending indices](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29).
- Making a copy of the array before sorting.
- Keeping the class stateless - all these methods could take anything required as arguments (while this is not strictly necessary, it will save you a lot of time in the future).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot I appreciate it!! I will try those thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Your method of calculating variance is wrong. Have a look at the definition of the variance (for instance on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StatisticalCalculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = { 49, 66, 73, 56, 3, 39, 33, 77, 54, 29 };

        double mean = getMean(array);
        double var = getVariance(array);
        double med = getMedian(array);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println("mean     : " + mean);
        System.out.println("variance : " + var);
        System.out.println("median   : " + med);
    }

    private static double getMean(double[] array) {
        int l = array.length;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            sum += array[i];
        return sum / l;
    }

    private static double getVariance(double[] array) {
        double mean = getMean(array);

        int l = array.length;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            sum += (array[i] - mean) * (array[i] - mean);
        return sum / l;
    }

    private static double getMedian(double[] array) {
        int l = array.length;
        // copy array to leave original one untouched by sorting
        double[] a = new double[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            a[i] = array[i];

        Arrays.sort(a);

        if (l % 2 == 0)
            return (a[l / 2 - 1] + a[l / 2]) / 2;
        else
            return a[(l - 1) / 2];
    }
}
```

Also, you have an issue with your array, as it is fixed size versus a variable size of user inputs. Consider using `ArrayList<Double>` or something similar as a container for your values to avoid this problem.

Comment: As for the array list, we cannot use array lists for this assignment otherwise I would've. and no, my variance formula is correct. heres the code you can test it yourself against an online variance calculator. Keep in mind this is the formula for a population and not a sample:

static double calcVariance (int inputs[], int count){
   
   sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    sumOfSquares += (inputs[i]*inputs[i]);
   }
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    sum = sum + inputs[i];
   }
   variance = ((sumOfSquares/count) - (sum * sum)/(count * count));
   return variance;
  }